# Using a variable number of rows in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=INDEX(TODAY!$D$2:TODAY!$D$306; MATCH(0; COUNTIF($A$2:$A2; TODAY!$D$2:TODAY!$D$306);0))
```

in the above example 306 is the number of ROWS in D column of the TODAY sheet that I get from the following formula:

```
=COUNTA(TODAY!D2:TODAY!D2000)
```

I can't figure out how to merge these two formulas together, so that in A column I get unique values for number of rows generated by second formula. Because if I copy the first formula along the A column it starts repeating from the beginning same values.

For example, what happens now is if I have 5 unique records in TODAY sheet but i copy the formula in 10 rows of A column it repeats those 5 records again. But I need to get only 5 records, others must remain blank.

Thank you!

Comment: Not behind a pc. But it should be something like `=TODAY!D2:INDEX(TODAY!D:D,....your formula to get the rows parameter))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use [`OFFSET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66).

Here's a list of animals and we want to count horses and the list can grow but it's fixed on `A2:A12`.

[image]

To make it dynamic use `OFFSET` and your `COUNTA` formula e.g.

```
OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNTA(A2:A40))
```

Which replaces the fixed `A2:A12` range in the example.

[image]